# Avoid mouseup event when selecting a file from dialog when double clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, mouseup

I have a `input[type="file"]` in my web page and when the file dialog is open and I select a file with double clicking the `mouseup` event is triggered. But if I select the file and then click the *Open* button to select there is no extra event.

This behavior is specific to Firefox, I tested in Chrome, IE and Opera and there is not extra `mouseup` event. Also there is no `mousedown` event, so the log will have two sequential `mouseup` events.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" />
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    //...
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/984a6ex9/1/) is a fiddle where you can see this behavior. To see it in action **make sure** that the file dialog is over the **Result** box of the jsfiddle page.

How can I avoid this? Is this a browser bug? Googling didn't come up with any useful results.

**Edit**: This issue appears on my Firefox (version 32.0.1 on Win7 64bit) but not on Firefox 32.0 in Linux.

Comment: Maybe you can use one of [these](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) which could indicate it's the dialog?

Comment: I looked at the properties of `e` but couldn't see something useful to detect its from a double click or it occurs after the file dialog closes.

Comment: A dodgy fix could be to unbind the mouseup when dialog is shown and re-bind when it closes. Not sure if it'll work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While looking a bit more into this I realized that this behaviour creates a stray `mouseup` event that is not fired after a `mousedown` event.

The fact that a `mouseup` event is always after a `mousedown` event is true in all modern browsers. The only case I found not to be true is when there is a `double-click` event in IE 5-8 ([Source](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html)).

So, the solution I used was to set a flag that a `mousedown` event occurs and that the `mouseup` event will occur the flag should be set to true.

For example:

```
var mousedown = false;

jQuery(document).mousedown(function (e) {
    mousedown = true;
});

jQuery(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (!mousedown) { // Stray mouseup event detected, handle it with 
        /*
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        */
    }
    mousedown = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try your code. I think its difficult without flag value because when double click the file, before releasing second click the menu will close and it will fire 'MouseUp' event.
I have solved it by using flag value. Please see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JarvisStark/uwkauk7g/2/).

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id='file1'/>
<div id="log"></div>
```

**Java Script**

```
var flag;
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {

    if(e.target.id != 'file1' && flag==1){
        flag = 0;
    }
    else if(e.target.id == 'file1'){
        flag = 1;        
        $('#log').prepend('mouseup: ' + (new Date()).toString() + '<br/>');
    }
    else{
        flag = 0;
        $('#log').prepend('mouseup: ' + (new Date()).toString() + '<br/>');
    }
});

$(document).mousedown(function(e) {

    $('#log').prepend('mousedown: ' + (new Date()).toString() + '<br />');

});
```

Thank you